# Oracle SQL Passing single quotes in the IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I writing a query to filter few records based on the ID as below. The issue is the emp_id is defined as Number in one Table and the other has Varchar. I need to pass single quotes within the IN CLAUSE

```
SELECT   emp_id, sal, name
from EMP1 -- here emp_id is defined as varchar 
where
 emp_id IN( Q'[Select empid from emp2]')-- as you can see i tried q'[]' to escape single quotes and doesn't work
```

Comment: It is likely that some of your  `emp_id` in one of the tables has non-numeric characters and hence it can't be compared with a number type column

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do does not make sense, and would just be placing a string literal SQL query into an `IN` clause, rather than all the `empid` values coming from the `emp2` table.  Instead, just use a regular subquery, and call `TO_NUMBER` on `emp_id` in the `EMP1` table so that it will compare correctly against `empid` in the `emp2` table.

```
SELECT emp_id, sal, name
FROM EMP1
WHERE TO_NUMBER(emp_id) IN (SELECT empid FROM emp2);
```

If the above query is still giving you problems, then it might imply that some of the data in the `emp_id` is not a proper number, or at least not something which `TO_NUMBER` can parse.  In this case, you could instead try casting the `empid` value in the subquery to character:

```
SELECT emp_id, sal, name
FROM EMP1
WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(empid) FROM emp2);
```

Comment: The reason is emp_id in EMP1 is a varchar, it need the value in quotes. If i pass the emp_id without quotes, I get invalid number. ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: Just cast one side to number/string before comparing, that is all.

Comment: I tried to_number on the EMP1.emp_id and still getting ORA-01722: invalid number. It works fine when i pass quotes for a sample emp_id

Comment: @APC Your comment belongs under the question, not under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

using a INNER JOIN  you could avoid the IN clause

```
  SELECT   emp_id, sal, name
  from EMP1 
  INNER JOIN EMP2 ON TO_CHAR(EMP2.empid) = EMP1.emp_id
```

and you can converting the data in ON condition

Comment: @GordonLinoff  thanks ..  I just thought of this for the conversion .. a number can always be converted to a string but the opposite is not always true